# Python 32bit "FindWindow" is not defined?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a bot made to run super hexagon (just for fun) at http://pastebin.com/X34Qxrxx

Unfortunately, whenever I run it with IDLE 3.5 32 bit, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 222, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 212, in main
window_handle = FindWindowLike(None, u"Super Hexagon").GetSafeHwnd()
NameError: name 'FindWindowLike' is not defined
```

Can anyone help? I'm not sure how to resolve this issue

Comment: Your code says `FindWindow`, your question says `FindWindowLike`. Also `win32ui.` is missing. What did you try to resolve the issue?

Comment: I originally had the Win32ui but it didn't work. I'm not sure how to resolve the issue

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work". You need to describe the exact problem you're trying to solve. The current code doesn't work, because you're trying to call a function which doesn't exist - there's no fix for that. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to reduce your problem to what's actually failing and try to find solution to that problem instead.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to define FindWindow

Comment: You don't. win32ui defines it: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32ui__FindWindow_meth.html There are multiple examples on google - like http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/14113/win32gui.FindWindow